# Redmine 3.4 reimport git repo

Tags: git, postgresql, redmine

I am trying to move an existing Redmine application from CentOS-6.9 to FreeBSd-12.0.

I have the Redmine application configured and running.  I have recreated the Redmine database contents on a new PostgreSQL RDBMS instance successfully.  The new redmine install connects to the database and displays the issues and wiki contents correctly.  However I cannot get the relocated git repository associated with the project to display.  I get this error:

```
404 The entry or revision was not found in the repository.
```

If I create a new redmine project pointing to an new bare repository, clone the new git repo, add a file to the clone, commit and push the update, then the new project opens the repo and displays the changes.

I delete that repo from the test project and add the old repo to the test project then I get the same error again. I have run git-fsck on the repo and it reports no errors.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Can Redmine server access that repo? There is no firewall blocking it or some othet problem, like ssl?

Comment: Maybe there is a file/directory permission issue with the copied repo?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was actually just the surface of a whole suit of issues.  Most having to do with file ownership and group permissions as suggested above.  Everything is now loaded into Redmine and the repository display appears to be working.